# javascript - regex involving escaped symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a problem.

If I try:

```
var stringTest = "stuff stuffthatIwant more stuff";
var stringRegex = stringTest.match("stuff (.*?) more");
```

stringRegex[1] returns: "stuffthatIwant".

but if I change the code to:

```
var stringTest = "stuff stuffthatIwant ? some stuff";
var stringRegex = stringTest.match("stuff (.*?) \?");
```

stringRegex[1] returns: "stuffthatIwant ? some stuff".

What should I do to use the "?" like I use the "more" on the first example?

Comment: What result do you want? `stuffthatIwant more stuff`?

Comment: You should pass the regex literal to `match`: `stringTest.match(/stuff (.*?) \?/);` or the string pattern is passed as an argument for the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: You'll have  to escape the backslash in the regex - `stuff (.*?) \\?`.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I want the "stuffthatIwant" only.

@ClasG I tried the \\?, but no success.

Comment: Actually, I cannot repro the last case. I can repro it with `/stuff (.*) ?/`. If you want `stuffIwant` - use `"stuff stuffthatIwant ? some stuff".match(/stuff (.*?) \?/)[1]`

Comment: [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La1zed2o/).

Comment: However, if it is a constant regex I'd go with @WiktorStribiżew sollution.

Comment: ^stuff\s+(\w+)(?:\s+more)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the regex literal to the `String.match()` method:

```
/stuff (.*?) \?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iT6gZ4/1)

When you pass a string to the `match` method, it is used to build a regex object with the `RegExp` constructor, and all backslashes should be doubled then. See the [`String.match()` MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If a non-RegExp object `obj` is passed, it is implicitly converted to a `RegExp` by using `new RegExp(obj)`.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "stuff stuffthatIwant ? some stuff".match(/stuff (.*?) \?/)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job!
And thanks @ClasG for the fiddle, too!